# How to intercept if my code is running on Web Warehouse Mobile Devices Portal?

Tags: web, axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++

It's possible in class `WHS...` `WHSWorkExecute` etc, childs class,  understand if they were launched from Web - [Warehouse Mobile Devices Portal](http://www.slideshare.net/lecadoujr/warehouse-mobile-device-portal-setting) or client AX?

Because do we need to condition a custom flow.

I tried to use :

```
if ( xGlobal::clientKind() )
{
 // my code Client Side 
 // can call class look like WinApi
}

else if ( ! xGlobal::clientKind() )
{
 // my code Server side - by Web Warehouse Mobile Devices Portal
 // I have to use class look like WinApiServer
}
```

But this possible solution not work well, I continues to enter in the client side.

I need to intercept if I'm running from web.

Thank in advice!

Answer (score 1):

You could try the global method [isRunningOnServer()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/global.isrunningonserver.aspx)

```
client server public static boolean isRunningOnServer()
```

Better solution would be not to use code that only works via the emulator (*WHSWorkExecute Form*) at all.

Comment: Hi @ztirom, thanks for answer. But I used `xGlobal::clientKind()` and don't work. There is difference between `xGlobal::clientKind()` and `Global::isRunningOnServer` ? IThanks for your time !